# Find the probability of $P(A)$ given $P(B)$ and $P(A|B)$?

Tags: probability

$A$,$B$,$C$ not independent, not mutually exclusive.

Also given: $P(C)$ and $P(C|A)$ but I didn't find these useful.
+Added: $P(A|-B)$

I can't seem to find the trick to get $P(A)$.

My attempts including using the General Conjuction Rule but that leads me back in a circle.

Comment: Is $P(A/B)$ supposed to be $P(A | B)$, e.g. the probability of event A given event B?

Comment: Yes. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$
2. $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$
3. $P(B^c)=1-P(B)$
4. $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$